# How to get shared Bash history among different tabs

Tags: bash, bashrc, history

I used the answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1292/41729 to enable real-time shared history among separate Bash terminals.
As explained in the answer above, this is achieved by adding the following to `.bashrc`:

```
# Avoid duplicates
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
# When the shell exits, append to the history file instead of overwriting it
shopt -s histappend

# After each command, save and reload history
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

This works fine if the Bash shells are separate (e.g. opening different Bash terminals using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. However it doesn't work if I use **tabs** (from an open terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) rather than new windows. Why this difference in behaviour? How can I share the Bash history also among various tabs?

**UPDATE:** I noticed an unusual behaviour: If I type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then the last command typed in any of the other terminals (both a tab or not) is correctly displayed. It is like if the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> forces a flush of the history so that then it is correctly shared.

As an example, the outputs (T1 denotes terminal 1 and T2 terminal 2):

```
T1:
ls -lah <enter>
# the list of files and directory is shown

T2:
cd Documents <enter>

T1:
<up> (i.e. I press the up arrow)
ls -lah # i.e the last command in terminal 1 is shown rather than the last of terminal 2
^C (i.e. I press CTRL+C)
<up>
cd Documents # the last command issued in terminal 2 is correctly displayed
```

Comment: You added that to your `~.bashrc` file? On a side note, exporting those variables is pointless; just wastes environment space.

Comment: @geirha yes I have added to my .bashrc file. Thanks for the comment on the export.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to access the other terminal's history *before* the sync takes place. `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed right before a new prompt is printed, i.e., **after** you run a command and before you type the next command. So it won't happen right away in T1; you have to cause a new prompt to be displayed.

To test this, try this variant on your steps (I added an extra `<enter>` in T1):

```
T1:
ls -lah <enter>
# the list of files and directory is shown

T2:
cd Documents <enter>

T1:
<enter>
<up> (i.e. I press the up arrow)
```

With this extra press of enter, you get a new prompt, which runs `PROMPT_COMMAND` and syncs your history, and so I would expect this up arrow to retrieve the `cd` instead of the `ls`, as you wanted. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to make the sync happen instantaneously in all terminals without running any commands as you seem to want; effectively this would require all of your login sessions to be synchronizing their history lists continuously all the time, which would be a huge waste of CPU and disk throughput.

Comment: you are right, pressing enter it is synced after. Even if there is a waste of memory or CPU how could I force the sync ?(if it is too much I can always disable it, but I would like to give it a try)

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question and here is the answer I came up with....

```
HISTSIZE=9000
HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace:ignoredups

history() {
  _bash_history_sync
  builtin history "$@"
}

_bash_history_sync() {
  builtin history -a         #1
  HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE     #2
  builtin history -c         #3
  builtin history -r         #4
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=_bash_history_sync
```

Comment: Source: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48116/37944

Comment: two clarfications before I try: should I remove the other hystory - options then? this goes in .bashrc right?

Comment: unfortunately it does not work...

Comment: Each time `HISTFILESIZE` is changed it automatically attempts to truncate the existing history file.  Changing `HISTSIZE` has a similar effect on the current history.  For reference, see the comment in `variables.c` in the bash src just before `sv_histsize`.

Answer (score 1):

add that lines to your `.bashrc` file

```
# avoid duplicates..
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  
# append history entries..
shopt -s histappend

trap 'history -r' USR1 
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a ; history -c; ps a | awk '/ bash$/ {system (\"kill -USR1 \" \$1)}'; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

note:

Initially I did my test bay sending USR1 signal to bash with killall, later I thought to use a uniquee shell name, a bash copy named testshell, to avoid killing my own shells that could run (cron processes for instance) but strangelly that was not working.

The killall was not selective enough, I  replaced it with a script that kills only the bash processes tight to a tty (`ps a` reports only processes tied to a tty)

Do not forget to restart your session to have a fresh PROMPT_COMMAND, when I was testing I saw many of my previous test stacked inside PROMPT_COMMAND.

Comment: You don't need the new user and the other shell, you can just tell `killall` to send the signal only to processes of the same user with an additional `-u` argument`, e.g. `-u $(whoami)`.

Comment: I think the syntax for csh is wrong...
@PhilippWendler could you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: The question is about bash, so I used bash syntax. I don't know csh. For bash, `killall -q -USR1 -u $(whoami) bash` sends USR1 signal to all bash processes of the current user.

Comment: @Philipp ty btw I didn't tested the dedicated shell solution, it was to fix a case where cron bash script would run.

Comment: @LucaCerone I rewrote seems to work

Comment: I get errors:
bash: export: `-USR1': not a valid identifier
bash: export: ` )}'; ': not a valid identifier
bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @LucaCerone oups sorry I forgot to escape the " and $. BTW note that you have to quit the session to reset the COMMAND_PROMPT you got when connecting first.

Comment: @Emmanuel I closed and opened the terminals. Now I don't get any error, but the history is not shared...

Comment: @LucaCerone after last edit it should have worked like a charm. chek if .bashrc is same as above, check  `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` to see if its not polluted. try `trap` to check if USR1 is trapped

Comment: @LucaCerone I'm mysel using now that setting, I found it verry handy

Comment: @Emmanuel maybe I am doing something wrong.. can you post your .bashrc file? I commented the commands that already contained export PROMPT_COMMAND history etc. and copied and pasted your code...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same strange behavior in Yakuake when tried to create elaborate bash prompt which would show the number of another logins. Number didn't increase for tabs.
My workaround was to tell Yakuake run `bash` again in every new tab, essentially starting bash in bash. It started to work flawlessly. May be it would help you too.
My blind guess is that GUI for console loads bash configs itself and then feeds them to bash instances. May be it is to be able to fiddle with them.

Comment: I have tried to load bash in bash, but without any success :(